# Google Earth Engine: Adding raster assets. How long can the ”Asset ingestion” take in Earth Engine after a successful upload?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to add a relatively large raster dataset (single band data, 8.05 GB GeoTiff, semi-global coverage) as an asset to Earth Engine through the web interface.

The upload succeeded, but now the status of **Ingest image** in the **Tasks** toolbar has been saying `State: Running on server` for 6 days and counting. There is no other status indicator.

I haven't had my own computer running continuously for that time, but this shouldn't make a difference after the upload was successful. Can it be expected that the task will finish at all, and if so, after what time, or should I just retry the asset ingestion?

Comment: Eventually this was the end result.

`State: Failed`
`Started: 11d ago (2020-01-17 12:21:04 +0200)`
`Runtime: 10d`

”Error: Unable to open _filename.tiff_”

Comment: In my experience if something doesn't upload within a few hours it's not going to work, though I've uploaded at most datasets that are about 1.2 GB. I'd say try importing a small clip of your raster and see if that works, in which case either make the resolution coarser or upload it by splitting it into regions.

Answer (score 0):

Please report the id of the failed task on the developers list: https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers

The first thing to check is whether the file is valid. Does gdalinfo work on it? Does gdal_translate work?